# CLI support for App Store app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, app-store, command-line-interface

Is there a way to add a command line interface to a *sandboxed* app downloaded through the Mac AppStore?

Something similar to the XCode command line tools, do not just use the whole executable name and path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done - app store rules don't allow to install code outside the app bundle. If you want to provide your users a CLI interface you'll have to make this available as a separate download outside the app store.

Comment: I hoped there would be an alternate solution.

Comment: Most apps keep the command line tool inside the app bundle, then offer a menu item for the user to manually install it into `/usr/local/bin` or wherever. Can't you even give the user a "Save To..." dialog under sandboxing?

Comment: @benzado App store apps aren't allowed to do that, even if they can. If you do that Apple will reject your app.

Comment: @Sven I was under the impression that you could give sandbox apps entitlements to access "user selected files" using NSSavePanels - and copy resources that way?

Comment: @Vervious yes, that is true. But this still doesn't mean that Apple will approve of you using it in that way.